# How to remove folders fully with Perforce P4V client after renaming folders?

Tags: windows, perforce

I use P4V to manage my Perforce files. One issue that is very confusing is that when I rename folders in P4V using Rename/Move, Perforce keeps the older version of the folder but with empty state. Basically the rename goes forward successfully but Perforce keeps the previous folders with no files in them.

Is there a way to get rid of the old folders after a rename or move?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your clientspec, make sure you have `rmdir` in the `Options` line, not `normdir`.

Comment: To expand on this a little -- the `rmdir` option makes it so that the *local* folder is deleted when the last of its files is deleted.  (You can also manually delete empty local folders with no ill effects.)  The folder will still be in the *depot* with the older versions of the deleted files, but it will not be synced to the client, and it will not be visible if you disable the option to "show deleted files".